# Giraph aggregators in InputFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, giraph

I am running some basic examples with Giraph and I want to verify the data being read by my `EdgeInputFormat`. On a classic MapReduce job I could do that using Counters and Giraph uses aggregators for this. (https://giraph.apache.org/aggregators.html)

It is said on the website that the aggregators should be registered on the master. The only code I wrote is a class that extends `BasicComputation` and implements the compute() method. Can somebody point Where should I register them and how do I use them while reading the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out how to do it.

I have implemented a class which extends `MasterCompute` and in the initialize() method I registered a persistent aggregator. I used `IntSumAggregator`.

After that, in `EdgeInputFormat` I could use `aggregate("myAggregator", new IntWritable(1));`.

The `MasterCompute` was set using `-mc` line argument.

Comment: Question: Where did you find examples of EdgeInputFormat being used? I looked quite a bit but found nothing concrete! Thank you.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but there might be something in the examples package. The documentation was also very useful.